# Moving a remote Wordpress multisite installation to local

Tags: multisite, localhost, local-installation, mac

I hope someone here can point me to some good resources to start moving my Wordpress multisite installation (already running for a year) to my local environment.

A lot of the tutorials out there are doing it the other way around (moving local WPMU to remote) or there about installing a clean install of WPMU locally, but I want to move everything with all my content right now.

I'm a Mac user so I got everything I need to run it locally. MAMP is working, I have my sync folder running to the remote location, but I'm getting stuck at moving the database to local and I have this plugin installed called 'domain mapping' and I'm not sure how this is going to work locally.

The software I prefer to use
MAC: Sublime text 2|3, MAMP pro, Codekit, SFTP, Chrome 
WEB: PHPmyadmin, wp Migrate DB Pro, WordPress MU Domain Mapping, Bitbucket

Comment: Go here : [MAMP on MAC](http://perishablepress.com/wordpress-multisite-mamp/), have fun ^^

Comment: that what i explained i got as far as that, but now i have the library of plugins i use that are not in a clean installation, how to move them over to local and who to get the database moved